# Regular expression involving modular arithmetic

Tags: regex, dfa

I'm trying to create DFA or regular expression for the language

> L = {a<sup>n</sup> b<sup>m</sup> | n mod 3 = m mod 3}`

For example, L contains the strings aaabbb, aaabbbbbb, and abbbb.

However, I'm getting stuck making any progress at all here. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Why? What don't you understand?

Comment: What's the divide in there doing? The expression doesn't always make sense.

Comment: Or makes even less sense. The first expression is an integer.

Comment: I dont understand how to make the same quotient for both the a and the b

Answer (score 4):

There are only three possible remainders modulo three. You can build a regular expression for the language by listing off regular expressions that handle each of the three cases, then unioning them together. Here's one possible answer:

```
(aaa)*(bbb)* | a(aaa)*b(bbb)* | aa(aaa)*bb(bbb)*
```

Hope this helps!